# Why must I resort to strings to get accurate number handling

Tags: python, decimal

When converting data to `decimal`, I sometimes still get incorrect results:

```
from decimal import *
D = Decimal
>>> D(5.2).quantize(D('.00000'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
Decimal('5.20000')
>>> D(5.3).quantize(D('.00000'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
Decimal('5.29999')
```

I don't think floating point imprecision is an excuse here since I'm using a specialized class to deal with the numbers! 
Quoted from the pyton docs:

> Decimal “is based on a floating-point model which was designed with
>   people in mind, and necessarily has a paramount guiding principle –
>   computers must provide an arithmetic that works in the same way as the
>   arithmetic that people learn at school.” – excerpt from the decimal
>   arithmetic specification

This works:

```
x=round(x - .0000049,5)
D(str(x) + (5-len(str(x).split('.')[1]))*'0')
```

Answer (score 10):

Because `5.3` by itself is *already wrong*.  When you pass it to `Decimal()`, that won't magically fix it.  You need to be using `Decimal()` at every step from the very beginning.  That means writing `Decimal('5.3')` instead of `Decimal(5.3)`.

EDIT: OP has stated they are using JSON.  Here's how you parse Decimals from JSON:

```
import json, decimal
decimal_decoder = json.JSONDecoder(parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
parsed_json = decimal_decoder.decode(raw_json)
```

(where `raw_json` is the JSON as a string).  This will produce correct Decimals.

Comment: So D(str(x)), a user still has to use strings to do proper arithmetic. I thought the point of the the Decimal library was to make it so one doesn't have to think about these things?

Comment: Verified: try doing just `D(5.3)` ; it returns `Decimal('5.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')`.  GIGO.

Comment: @user3467349: Where did you get `5.3`, anyway?  If the user gave it to you, just don't call `float()` on it in the first place (or use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, under Python 2).

Comment: It's JSON. Yes it seems Decimal just takes the pointer for the float in memory which json.loads parses by default. My question isn't about 5.3 being wrong it's about why a library that's supposed to give regular arithmetic can't take care of byte magic without the user parsing strings.

Comment: @user3467349: unfortunately no, the purpose of the class is to provide a tool for base-10 arithmetic. There is no tool that allows you to pass the wrong input in and nevertheless get the right output out. `5.3` is what it is. "On two occasions I have been asked 'Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?'
I am not able rightly to comprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question." ;-)

Comment: @user3467349: For good or ill, a programmer doing floating-point math **must** have some awareness of how floating point works if they hope to get it right. The number 5.3 **has no exact binary floating point representation**. So once your data is in floating point form, it is already incorrect.

Comment: @JohnY There lots of people that use Python who are not programmers - why a library that's supposed to hide binary repr. inits to explicit float instead of a str version is quite beyond me.

Comment: @user3467349 but it doesn't! It's nothing to do with the library! Your `5.3` is *already a float*, as others have explained, *even before it gets to Decimal*.

Comment: @Daniel Yes it's float and instead of hiding the fact Decimal makes it explicit. It's annoying and I can't see one reasonable use for that.

Comment: @user: How exactly do you expect Decimal to magically transform `5.299...` (which is what you actually have; the interactive prompt is just rounding it when displaying it) into `'5.3'`?  Should it just guess that you really meant the latter?  Round and hope for the best?  Because that will inevitably be wrong at some point.

Comment: `Decimal` in principle could throw an exception when passed a floating-point input, and only accept a string. This would increase convenience for people who don't know what a float is (or who for some other reason don't want to use floats), at the cost of decreasing convenience for people who do (and who want to convert floats to `Decimal`). As a member of the former constituency, the questioner naturally thinks Python should cater to the former: as members of the latter we think otherwise :-)

Comment: Also for reference, what `5.3` means in Python is "a float with numeric value 5.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875". No library is able to make it mean anything different from that, it's part of the language definition. So of course, if you pass a numeric value of 5.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 to `Decimal`, you get a decimal object with the same value. If you want a Decimal object with value 5.3 do what Kevin says: pass it `'5.3'`, not `5.3`.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are wrong. The literal 5.3 is invalid (as Kevin has already stated).

The problem here is that you cannot start from an invalid representation (a float one) and then assume that magic will happen and fix everything.

It is easy to build a sane environment:

```
a = D(53)
b = D(10)
c = a/b
```

And then `c` is a valid number.

The problem is: where does your decimal number come from? If you have 5.3 and want a valid representation, you are asking a valid representation of a number that you have as a string. Then, you need to use the string. If you have a division, then take advantage of that and do the operation in the `decimal.Decimal` environment. If the user has passed a number, keep it as string and then convert it to Decimal directly, etc.

Bonus edit: Remember that

```
$ 5.2999999999999999 == 5.3
> True
```

That is what means that "literal representation is wrong" (from your point of view and constraints). Using `5.3` as a float implies this problem.